# Summer '17 sandbox for a Spring '17 org

Tags: sandbox, spring17, summer-17

I have an org that is currently in Spring '17, and I want to create a sandbox in Summer '17.

Is there a way I can declare what version of sandbox I want and will the sandbox always be created in the same version as the production org?

Comment: The issue arose when I set up a new org after the cut-off date. The long time between the cutoff and activation/go-live date (over a month) causes an issue when doing a small deploy fro an enterprise org where dev is done in the sandbox and deployed to production. So even though go-live will be after Summer '17 release date the sandbox can not be upgraded to Summer'17 until after the production org goes live.

Comment: What is this "org" you speak of?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It's just an abbreviation for "organization."  Sometimes it's used to differentiate the production instance ("org") from development sandboxes, although some people also use "dev org."

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Nope, you can't request a Summer 17 org at this time. The version is controlled during the [new release preview](https://www.salesforce.com/blog/2017/03/salesforce-summer-17-sandbox-preview-instructions.html). Generally, depending on the pod your sandbox is on, you must either refresh during a certain window, or not refresh during a certain window. This release's refresh window has already happened, but for future releases, make sure you subscribe to admin emails (on your user record), and pay attention to the preview release post that is sent out about 2-4 weeks before the window occurs.